# PHP control if image url is referring to specific image EXT

Tags: php, image, validation, url, mime-types

i wrote this function:

```
function isImage($url)
  {

     $params = array('http' => array(
                  'method' => 'HEAD'
               ));
     $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
     $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
     if (!$fp) 
        return false;  // Problem with url

    $meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
    if ($meta === false)
    {
        fclose($fp);
        return false;  // Problem reading data from url
    }

    $wrapper_data = $meta["wrapper_data"];
    if(is_array($wrapper_data)){
      foreach(array_keys($wrapper_data) as $hh){
          if(substr($wrapper_data[$hh], 0, 19) == "Content-Type: image") // strlen("Content-Type: image") == 19 
          {
            fclose($fp);
            return true;
          }
      }
    }

    fclose($fp);
    return false;
  }
```

It does checks if a  url returns an image type, now i would like to extend  this method controlling if returned image's extension  is in array  ('png','jpeg','jpg').

i need this control, cause of users submitting image urls on my app.

Any suggestion will be appriciated!

Comment: And your question is...? We're not a code critiquing service. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet will return you the image type along with the checking if it's an image :

```
    function get_type ($url) {

    $mimes = array (    'bmp'   =>  array('image/bmp', 'image/x-windows-bmp'),
                    'gif'   =>  'image/gif',
                    'jpeg'  =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
                    'jpg'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
                    'jpe'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
                    'png'   =>  array('image/png',  'image/x-png')
            ) ;

    $info  = getimagesize($url);

    //$info['mime'] = 'image/gif';

    if ($info['mime']) {
        if ($type = array_search ($info ['mime'],$mimes)) 
            return $type;
        else {
            foreach ($mimes as $key=>$value) {
                if (is_array ($value) ) {
                    if ( !( FALSE === array_search ($info['mime'] , $value ) ))
                        return $key;
                }
            }
        }//end of else
    }
    else return "Not an image";

}
```

If you call this function with this :

```
echo get_type("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/701467343cbd095506ca24b1ee5406d8?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG");
```

It will return `png`.

And if you call with this url :

```
echo get_type("http://www.google.com");
```

It will return `Not an image`.

Hope that helps . Happy coding :)

Comment: well i think i can totally replace my method with the one you showed me, cause actually, if your method doesn't returns the ext the url is not returning an image at all (related to my app needs obviously)

Comment: That will be a pleasure, sire :)

Comment: eheheh , call me ispuk call me ispuk :D

Answer (score 1):

Check if "Content-Type" header is one those:

1. Content-Type:image/png
2. Content-Type:image/jpeg
3. Content-Type:image/jpg

or

Check if the `$url` argument ends with ".png", ".jpg" or ".jpeg"

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet can help you if i got you right :

```
$info  = getimagesize("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/701467343cbd095506ca24b1ee5406d8?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG");
echo $info['mime'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I personaly would prefer a `preg_match` just like this:

```
    $allowed_file_types = "(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|png)";
    if(preg_match("/\." . $allowed_file_types . "$/i", 'image.jpg'))
    {
         // The file extention is allowed
    }
    else
    {
        // Not allowed!
    }
```

Comment: yes but what if submit site.com/image.png.gif?

Answer (score 0):

To get information about file from some url, you can use this code:

```
<?php
//the request
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);

// get the content type
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
?>
```

will output:
text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1